# Excel VBA: Delete any empty Excel file in folder

Tags: excel, vba, file, directory

I'd like to be able to search a folder of `.xls` files and delete any file from the folder that is empty. When I say empty, I mean there are either no sheets in the file or there is not any data in any cells, if a sheet does exist.

CODE:

```
Sub DeleteEmptyFiles()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FolderPath = "Enter the folder path here"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    'DELETE FILE IF EMPTY

    Next ws
    
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: All workbooks will have at least one sheet

Comment: In addition to what @Warcupine said, you can then find the next empty cell for each sheet and use the beginning cell as a range to see if it's true. [This](https://sitestory.dk/excel_vba/find-next-empty-cell.htm) should help.

Comment: @Mike some important updates were made to your accepted answer, after you accepted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```vb
Sub DeleteEmptyFiles()
 Dim FolderPath As String, Filename As String, wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet, boolNotEmpty As Boolean
 Dim previousSecurity As MsoAutomationSecurity

 FolderPath = "Enter the folder path here" 'Take care to end the folder path in "\"
                                           'Otherwise, build the file full name inserting "\"
 Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

 Do While Filename <> ""
    previousSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderPath & Filename)
    Application.AutomationSecurity = previousSecurity
    
    boolNotEmpty = False
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.UsedRange) > 0 Then
            boolNotEmpty = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    wb.Close False
    If Not boolNotEmpty Then Kill FolderPath & Filename
    Filename = Dir()
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @chris neilsen: Of course it must be `ws.UsedRange`! I tested the code line on a new empty sheet and forgot adapting it to the iteration worksheet. Not bad to disable macros. I will also do that. Even if less probable (he should mention that, I think) a different kind of sheets to be involved, I will adapt the code to process as above only the worksheets. I would assume that if such non-worksheet sheets exists, they are there with a purpose. If he also need to check them for emptiness, he must state it... Thanks! Edited: adapted.

Comment: I took the liberty of making some correction to your update.  I hope you don't mind

Comment: @chris neilsen: Of course, not. I missed `previousSecurity` declaration and giving it a value... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells()) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "the Sheet " & ws.Name & " contents data "
         
        Exit For
    Else
      
     MsgBox "no data in " & ws.Name
    End If
   
    
    Next ws
    
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()

Loop
```

Comment: This code will display a message box stating whether or not the file has data or not, but does not kill the file if no data is found.

Comment: instead of msgBox, I let you create the code to delete the file.  like this 
Dim fso as New FileSystemObject, aFile as File

if (fso.FileExists("PathToFile")) then
    aFile = fso.GetFile("PathToFile")
    aFile.Delete
End if